# How to write URLs that are not automatically linked?

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

When I write a bare HTTP URL on a SE site, it's automatically linked. For example:

```
http://example.com
```

shows as:

http://example.com

But when the URL is not real, I don't want to make it a link. But I also don't want to make it look like code (by using backtics `` ` ``).

Comment: @random Thanks, that does answer my question. Somehow I didn't find it when searching.

Answer (score 4):

You can insert an empty HTML comment (`<!---->`) into the middle of the URL to fool the autolinking. For example:

```
h<!---->ttp://invalidexample.com
```

Shows as:

http://invalidexample.com

Comment: Note that while this workaround does work, I am still interested to see if there is a better solution.

Comment: Why didn't you post this in your question as "I've tried this but want a better solution"? This reads like a self answered question pair, as if you're providing help for others/ I've added it to your question. Might be worth deleting this answer now :)

Comment: @James Because I thought it might actually be useful for others and that I would accept this answer if somebody else didn't figure out something better. (But that's now moot, the duplicate does answer my question.)